# Google mobile compose page URL

Tags: android, android-intent, google-plus

I want to send a predifined google+ message via android, but I\m  not sure I found the right URL for that. I found https://plus.google.com/app/plus/mp/430/#~loop:view=compose , but it's not setting my text. Is there actually another official app URL that could allow that? Twitter has the one bellow. 10x

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, msg);
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse("https://mobile.twitter.com/compose/tweet"));
ctx.startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can share text and images on Google+ with the `ACTION_SEND` intent.

Example:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hello World!");
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(shareIntent);
```

If you would like to target the Google+ app directly, you can call setPackage on the `shareIntent` before calling `startActivity`.

```
shareIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.plus");
```